# GCD and Simple Path

Tags: data-structures, graph, greatest-common-divisor

Given an undirected and connected graph of `N vertices and N-1 edges`. The number written on the `ith` vertex is `val[i]`. The task is to count the number of pairs (x, y) such that following conditions are satisfied:

> 1. 0 ≤ x < y ≤ N-1
> 2. The GCD of the numbers written on the vertices on the simple path in the given graph from x to
>    y should be divisible by K.

**Example:**

Input:
N = 4, K = 2
Edges[] = {{0, 1}, {0, 2}, {2, 3}}
Val[] = {2, 6, 4, 3}
**Output:**
3
**Explanation:**
0 - 1
|
2 - 3
There are three pairs - (0,1), (1,2) and
(0,2) which satisify both the conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two observations here:

1)It is a connected graph and it has n-1 edges. So it has to be a tree.

2)For condition 2 to be true, all the numbers written on the nodes in the simple path between x and y has to be k or a multiple of k.

With these two observations we can devise a solution

> 1. Replace all val[i]'s with val[i]%k.
> 2. Foreach i from 0 to n-1:
>
>    a. if val[i]==0, and not visited before Run a dfs from node i.
>
>    b. In dfs only visit the nodes for which val[node]=0 and not visited before. Return the number of nodes you visited on this run. Let this number be x. Also mark these nodes visited.
>
>    c. Add xC2 = (x*(x-1))/2 to the answer. (Why? because all the pairs of these visited nodes satisfies both of our conditions. We can select 2 nodes in xC2 ways.).